# Where can I ask help with Ethernet jacket colours?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following, but was not sure whether it best fit into Super User, Server Fault or perhaps somewhere else.

> **Which Ethernet cable jacket colours should I use?**
>
> We have the following connections
>
> - Patch panel to non-PoE switch
> - Patch panel to CCTV, PoE
> - Patch panel to WiFi access point, PoE
> - Patch panel to Floodlight, PoE
> - WAN to router
>
> We are trying to follow the ethernet jacket colour coding standards.
>
> [image: Ethernet Jacket Colours]
>
> I do not understand the aforementioned colour descriptions, as it would appear that none of them are applicable. Which colours should we use in the rack?

Thanks!

Comment: Asked at [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76328/39690) as suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd personally go with [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

> Network Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.